# Filter pictures in directory

Tags: gps, sorting, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a drone project with 50,000 pictures in 50 layers.
Each layer has 2 to 5 zones.

When I put them all together, we have a lot of overlap and in some places, we have up to 4 pictures of the same area. See the basic example below:
[image]

I want to make a mosaic using as little pictures as possible.

How can I use the standard layer management features to manage my imported points and then delete the associated source file or export only the files I need to a new file?

Regards,

Alan C

Comment: what GIS software?

Comment: Hi csk, thank you for your question. I have QGIS but my office also has ArcGIS

Comment: The rules for this site say you should pick one software and tag your question with it. Otherwise this question will likely be closed as "too broad."

Comment: What rules would you use to discard certain photos? Looks like you have 3 separate flights - is there an order of precedence?